# Is using Scale effect in render loop faster than pre-scaling bitmap?

Tags: c++, direct2d

Currently I draw images next way:

1. During load, using WIC, I obtain the original bitmap, store it as a property in object, that represents an image (`ID2D1Bitmap *imageOriginal` property).
2. Then (still at load time), I create compatible render target with the size I need image to be.
3. Draw image to the compatible target using scale effect.
4. Allocate new bitmap as property of object that represents an image (`ID2D1Bitmap *imageScaled` property).
5. Copy from compatible target to `imageScaled`.
6. Free compatible target. Here image load ends.

When already created image object need to be resized, I repeat steps 2-6. In the result, in render loop I have to only draw `imageScaled`.

I currently thinking about of removing 2-6 steps and just draw scale effect with `imageOriginal` passed from each image object in the render loop every time.

I do not know what exactly Direct2d `Scale` effect does. If it actually every time does something similar to steps 2-6, then, probably I don't need to do it.

In the other hand, in my render loop there is basic skip algorithm for objects that are out of parent view, so they are not drawn at all. In current realization I may need to wait time for pre scale objects that possibly out of view, and they will not be drawn currently. With `Scale` effect in render loop realization this problem will be solved.

Does anyone know which solution will be the fastest?

Comment: Facts are: GPU is generally the fastest for manipulating images, Direct2D is a GPU technology that sits on DirectX (and contains shaders we get for free), Direct2D scale effect runs in GPU, GPU => CPU and CPU => GPU are costly operations, WIC is a CPU technology. With that in mind, it's difficult to answer because if you seem to mix things. The best is to test your whole pipeline.

Comment: @SimonMourier, maybe **I** didn't catch that, but it seems **You** wrote something unrelated, perhaps didn't understand the question

Comment: Apparently **I** was the only one interested. Perhaps **your** question cannot be answered easily.

Comment: @SimonMourier, yeah, I appreciate that, I just pointed, that as I read Your comment, it was barely related. And yes, it is practical question, so I waited for people who have been writing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

After rewriting my code, currently it seems that using `Scale` in render loop is faster for a single image.

Again, before that, when `setImage` method of the object that represents UI an image is called, something like that was happening:

```
void ImageObject::setImage(const wchar_t *path)
{
     if(!wcscmp(this->path, path))
          return;
     SafeRelease(&this->originalImage);
     
     // Load original image via WIC

     this->scaledImage = RescaleImage(this->originalImage, this->width, this->height);
}
```

And in the main render loop:

```
void ImageObject::Render() 
// render loop iterates through ImageObject objects array and calls each object's Render method
{
// skip is cached variable simply equals 
// (this->x > this->parent->width || this->y > this->parent->height || etc)
     if(skip) 
         return;

     renderTarget->DrawBitmap(this->originalImage, rectangle);
}
```

Now it is like this:

```
void ImageObject::setImage(const wchar_t *path)
{
     if(!wcscmp(this->path, path))
          return;
     SafeRelease(&this->originalImage);
     
     // Obtain originalImage and that's it
}

void ImageObject::Render() 
{
     if(skip) 
         return;

     globalScale->SetInput(0, this->originalImage);
     globalScale->SetValue(D2D1_SCALE_PROP_SCALE, ...);

     renderTarget->DrawImage(globalScale, point);
}
```

First method actually supposed to be more faster, because in the render I need to just draw plain bitmap.

As I wrote in the post, I though the second method should work faster in case of big amount of images, when part of them are out of screen, but currently, with this method, drawing one image is faster than with image prescaling method.